# Django Model.objects.last() returning second to last instance instead of the very last instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of building a Django app, which is meant to be a self updating inventory app for a hypothetical restaurant. I have a model, "Purchase", which uses another model "Register" as a ForeignKey field. I have it set the reference to the last instance created of Register so that any entree purchase is linked to the currently active register at the store. The problem is that when a Purchase instance saves, it keeps referencing the second to last Register object instead of the last.

Here is the current model code for those two models:

```
class Register(models.Model):
    daily_bank = models.FloatField(default=500)
    amount_spent = models.FloatField(default=0)
    amount_made = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today) 
    def sales(self):
        lst = []
        for p in self.purchase_set.all():
            if p.menu_item not in lst:
                lst.append([p.menu_item.title, 1])
            else:
                for entry in lst:
                    if entry[0] == p.menu_item.title:
                        entry[1] = entry[1] + 1
        return lst
    def profit(self):
        if self.id > 1:
            return self.daily_bank - Register.objects.get(id=self.id-1).daily_bank
        else:
            return self.daily_bank - 500
    def last(self):
        return self == Register.objects.last()

class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    time = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    register = models.ForeignKey(Register, on_delete=CASCADE, default=Register.objects.last())
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item_name = self.menu_item.title
        if self.pk is None:
            for i in self.menu_item.reciperequirment_set.all():
                if i.menu_item == self.menu_item:
                    i.ingredient.quantity -= i.required_amount 
                    i.ingredient.save()
        super(Purchase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also have a Signal going on in the background when a new Purchase is made if that might be part of the issue?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Purchase)
def sale(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        n = Register.objects.last()
        n.daily_bank += instance.menu_item.price
        n.amount_made += instance.menu_item.price 
        n.save()
    else:
        pass
```

Additionally this is the function I created inside another model, MenuItem, that is running in the background to provide the Purchase count for that Register

```
def sales(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.purchase_set.all():
            if i.register == Register.objects.order_by("id").last():
                count += 1
        count = str(count)
        return count
```

Any ideas why Register.objects.last() isn't returning the actual last instance?

Comment: specify order_by, databases are not required to return rows in the same order everytime

Comment: Ok thank you didn't realize. Also since I give the user to option to create new Register instances of the same day, should i maybe add a time field as well?

Comment: a Databases primary key, "id", is auto-incremented so you could order by "id", otherwise you can use a `DateTimeField`

Comment: Ok I made the change and what seems to be happening is it will work in the app immediately after making the change, but once i create a new Register instance it stops working again. Basically any time I adjust it to any viable order_by parameter it will briefly work and then repeat the problem after the new instance

Comment: `Register.objects.order_by('id')` is returning items out of order? What database are you using? Do you have caching setup? Are you only retrieving the last Register when the server is initially started?

Comment: Yes, I adjusted the code for Purchase's field to now read: register = models.ForeignKey(Register, on_delete=CASCADE, default=Register.objects.order_by("id").last()). But this is still causing it to reference the second to last Register object

Comment: your model definitions are ran when your server starts, so it is setting the default when your server starts, try setting `default=get_last_register` and defining the function `def get_last_register():` to `return Register.objects.order_by("id").last()`

Comment: That solved it! Thank you Jimmy, I've been trying to solve that on my own for a long time. Also want to ask, when you say setting the default then the server starts, does that mean its saving that current last Register object and then feeding it to new instances of Purchase instead of rechecking every time? And so making it a function causes it to actually recheck the query? Hope that question makes sense

Comment: That is correct, when python loads your project it reads all your class definitions, at that moment is when it reads your `default`, since your default executed a function as indicated by the parenthesis in your function call to `last()` python executed that function for you to set your default, when you just pass the function name instead to python it understands it should only call that function when needed which would be on creating a new `Purchase` instance